# Validation is not working in bootstrap html

Tags: javascript, html, validation, twitter-bootstrap-3

I gave a validation to test field by giving required to it as

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="inputEmail" class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-1  control-label">Email address</label>
  <div class="col-lg-4">
    <input class="form-control" ng-model="$root.customerDetails.eMail" placeholder="Enter customer email" type="email" required focus value = "{{emailId}}">
  </div>
</div>
```

and then i'm clicking submit button,but the validation is not working. I'm able to proceed to next page with out email.

Is there any other way to do the validation.

Can someone help me
Thanks

It should be like:

[image]

Comment: Try using `required="true"` instated of using just `required`

Comment: Thanks..but even that is not working

Comment: Can you please confirm whether you have your `<form>` tag on top your bootstrap container div? Something like this, http://jsfiddle.net/hTPY7/4231/

Comment: @DavidR yes iam having

Comment: Do you have `ng-submit` on your form? In other words, what do you do to submit the `form`?

Comment: Iam having ng-click

Answer (score 0):

The validation not stop the submission automatically. In your submit function you need to check if the forum is valid.

Like this:

```js
angular.module('app', []).
controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.submit = function() {
    console.log('submitted');  
  }
});
```

```css
.validation {
  font-size: 80%;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <form name="myForm">
    <input type="text" name="txt" ng-model="txt" required /><br />
    <!--<div class="validation" ng-show="myForm.$submitted && myForm.txt.$invalid">Please fill out the field</div>-->
    <button ng-click="myForm.$valid && submit()">Submit</button><br />
    Form is valid: {{myForm.$valid}}
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thnks..But I need something like Please fill out the field when we get  on using required ,when we click submit to text field with no value..Is it possible

Comment: .I added an image to question..It should be like that..We will get that when we use required.how to get that inside a form

Comment: Just remove the `novalidate` attribute from the `form`.

Comment: Hi @mosh The popup validation is working but,when i enter a value and click submit,I was able to submit ,but again I was getting pop-up

Comment: Have you added the `myForm.$valid`? To the `ng-click` attribute?

Comment: Yes added and the still the problem exists

Comment: Any errors in the console? Try to add the `{{myForm.$valid}}` to the view to check if it valid. Which angular version are you using? Do you have a public URL of your project or can you create a bin?

Comment: .The problem is, i have the form in one html and the button and the ng-click in another html.Im reusing the code here.

Comment: how can we make this work if button is outside of the form tag?

Comment: Are the button and the form in the same controller?